# How to enable light mode/dark mode in Windows 11 programatically?

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, windows-11, themes

I'm trying to schedule the light mode/dark mode in Windows personalization settings using Task scheduler, so that Windows theme colors will change based on time of day, which is also better for eyes.

These 2 keys are the only ones responsible for it:

```
# Set Windows Personalization, color settings, to enable Light mode for System
$RegistryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize'  
$Name         = 'SystemUsesLightTheme'  
$Value        = '1' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force

# Set Windows Personalization, color settings, to enable Light mode for Apps
$RegistryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize'  
$Name         = 'AppsUseLightTheme'  
$Value        = '1' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

Running that only partially changes the Windows theme from dark to light, like the taskbar and file explorer aren't changed, but settings page itself and some other areas are changed.

What other component are responsible, other than registry, that perform these personalization tasks?

I've traced the settings process when changing the theme and no other registry key other than those 2 are modified.

Changing the theme using settings is the only way I found so far that performs the theme change properly.

Comment: The registry is just a place to store settings, it is not the program that does the changes. You might have watched the program change the setting, but did you run whatever library or command actually *actions* the changes? You might have to reboot to see a change after just editing the registry.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, that's what I thought, looking for a way to action those changes, without reboot, just like Windows settings does it.

Comment: @zerogainer - Out of pure interest. If you implement your registry key changes then log out of the user do all expected changes happen? If they do not then there must be other keys your not changing that need to change. Of course i am with others that indicated your not supposed to be able to do what you want by simply changing the registry.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, realized modifying the registry wasn't something I wanted after all, because it'd create a new custom theme and add it to personalization settings. posted my answer that does exactly what I want without modifying any system files.

Comment: I used exactly the mentioned registry items to switch between light and dark mode since almost a year without any problems (no other action was necessary to actually trigger the switch of themes) - just until the previous major Windows 11 update. Now it seems that there is a third bit of information necessary, which I haven't been able to find yet.

Answer (score 3):

Well, turns out I don't need the registry at all.

Windows 11 saves the built-in themes in this directory:

```
C:\Windows\Resources\Themes
```

after checking the ACLs there, I noticed all users have the read and execute permissions, so no need to modify any permissions there.

these 4 files which are built-in themes are important,

1. themeA.theme
2. themeB.theme
3. themeC.theme
4. themeD.theme

the first 2 are dark mode, the other 2 are light mode

so just created 4 task schedules via PowerShell so that the first 2 dark themes will be used from 6PM till 8:59AM, and from 9AM to 5:59PM the Light themes will be used.

```
# Task Schedules

$user = "ENTER YOUR USERNAME"

# Dark Theme A
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\themeA.theme"

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 6PM
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskPath "Theme Scheduling" -TaskName "Dark ThemeA" -Description "Activates Dark Theme everyday at 6PM" -User $user -RunLevel Limited 


# Dark Theme B

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\themeB.theme"

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12AM
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskPath "Theme Scheduling" -TaskName "Dark ThemeB" -Description "Activates Dark Theme everyday at 12AM" -User $user -RunLevel Limited 




# Light Theme C

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\themeC.theme"

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9AM
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskPath "Theme Scheduling" -TaskName "Light ThemeC" -Description "Activates Light Theme everyday at 9AM" -User $user -RunLevel Limited 

  


# Light Theme D

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\themeD.theme"

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 2PM
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskPath "Theme Scheduling" -TaskName "Light ThemeD" -Description "Activates Light Theme everyday at 2PM" -User $user -RunLevel Limited
```

The reason I wanted to do this is because this is the smart way to have the OS change themes based on time of day, also better for eyes.

this is also one of the [top feedback items in the Feedback Hub](https://aka.ms/AA98751) that people voted for, I think Microsoft will eventually implement this feature, but until then, use the PowerShell script above.

Comment: May I suggest you edit the question to better reflect this: "change themes based on time of day, also better for eyes".

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I edited my question